# Send an item of an ArrayList to end

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, kotlin

I have an ArrayList like this:

```
val myArrayList = ArrayList<String>()

myArrayList.add("a")
myArrayList.add("b")
myArrayList.add("c")
```

Until now, "a" is the index 0, "b" is the index 1 and "c" is the index 2. But I want "a" to go to the end of the ArrayList. I mean I want the indexes to be like this: "b" index 0, "c" index 1, "a" index 2.

Do you know how is it possible?

Comment: you can use a swap function to swap after adding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.swap(List<?> list, int i, int j);`

Like this `Collections.swap(myArrayList, 0, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
       myArrayList.add("a");
        myArrayList.add("b");
        myArrayList.add("c");         
        Collections.swap(myArrayList, 1, 2);   
        Collections.swap(myArrayList, 2, 0);    
       Log.e("output",myArrayList.toString());
```

**Output**

**[b, c, a]**

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution:

```
java.util.Collections.rotate(myArrayList, -1)
```

This way, the size of the list will not matter, even if the list is empty.

Try it in the [Kotlin Playground](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/njfes9rd700up6hjh17r9s2m51/uiirm4drb884oucabge9ammpe8)

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways you can solve this problem. The ArrayList add method (with one parameter) automatically appends whatever you're adding to the end of the list. Here's two ways to solve it:

```
myArrayList.add("c")
myArrayList.add("b")
myArrayList.add("a")
```

The order of these three method calls matter in the case above. You can also do this:

```
myArrayList.add(0, "c")
myArrayList.add(1, "b")
myArrayList.add(2, "a")
```

In this case, the order the three method calls don't matter.

Comment: No I know that. I want to change the indexes whenever I want whenever it's needed

Comment: You would have to create a swap function because there are no in built swap methods in the ArrayList class.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and give an example of this swap function?